# Unit test a module with Jest in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, node-modules

I hope you are well.
I'm trying to test my registerContact() function (according to the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)) which is in another file with the Jest package but it gives me an error while running the test.

Here is how I proceed with the test

```
import contactsController from '../../src/api/endpoints/contacts/contacts_routes_controller.js'

describe('Test de la methode registerContact', () => {

    test(`
    Test avec le champs address manquant.
    Doit renvoyer une exception avec le message d'erreur "address-field-required"`, async () => {
        const contact = {
            email: "myemail.d@email.com",
            phone: "+16848554575",
            district: "dc"
        }



        try {
            await contactsController.registrerContact(contact)

        } catch (err) {
            expect(err).toMatch('error')
        }


    })
})
```

Here is the error that Jest returns in the terminal

```
> aw_server@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/endpoints/contacts.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    E:\stormbreaker\NodeJsProjects\aw_server\__tests__\endpoints\contacts.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import contactsController from '../../src/api/endpoints/contacts/contacts_routes_controller.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1773:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.626 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I went through the [Jest documentation at the url that the error was returning](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) to me in the terminal about the configuration and didn't get out of it.

I did some research but I didn't find anything concrete.

Can you tell me the cause of the error and how to solve it?

P.S: I use a NodeJs environment.

Comment: Did you take into account the link https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules ?

Comment: It looks like you imported your function from your source folder (`../../src/api/endpoints/`).  If you are using Typescript, etc., you need the transpiled version of the code so it is the Javascript code.  With Typescript you need ts-node.  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Comment: @StevenScott i'm not using Typescript

Comment: @Anatoly when i'm running Jest like this "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js" it's works